# Python tuple() : when does it reorder?

Tags: python, set

I am using Python 3.7 and get confused at tuple(). Sometimes it re-order the data, sometimes not:

```
>>> a=tuple([2, 1, 3])
>>> print(a)
(2, 1, 3)   <== the tuple from list is not re-ordered

>>> s={2, 1, 3}
>>> b=tuple(s)
>>> print(b)
(1, 2, 3)   <== the tuple from set is re-ordered

>>> print(tuple({10, 5, 30}))
(10, 5, 30)  <== the tuple from set is not re-ordered

>>> print(s)
{1, 2, 3}    <== the set itself is re-ordered
```

I have 2 questions:

> 1. What are expected behavior of tuple() as of whether:
>
>    1.1 Generate an ordered tuple?
>
>    1.2 Modify the input?
> 2. Where can I find the definitive documentation? I checked Python on-line doc, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple, it
>      does not provide such info at all.

Thanks.

Comment: The set is already re-ordered, nothing to do with tuple.

Comment: `{10, 5, 30}` just happens to be ordered as `10, 5, 30`.

Comment: `tuple` **never reorders data**. `set` objects *are inherently unordered*

Answer (score 5):

A set is unordered, and a list is ordered. So `tuple(a_list)` retains the order of the list but `tuple(a_set)` has no stated order to follow.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the link you shared:

> The constructor builds a tuple whose items are the same and **in the same order as iterable’s items**.

Because `set` is un-ordered by definition, if you pass `set` as iterable to `tuple()` function there is no way to know/guarantee the order.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are by definition an ordered data structure and their constructor is `tuple()` .

In your case, if you're using `{}`, its not a tuple but a set and therefore not ordered.

You can find the official python tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). In 5.3 they also address tuples specifically

Comment: `{a:b}` constructs a dictionary. `{a,b}` costructs a set. There is never ambiguity about which one is denoted by curly braces.

Comment: sets and dictionarys both use curly braces. I was just referring to the {} braces, not to the notation inside them.

Comment: `()` is not a tuple constructor, it is part of a tuple literal, same with `{}`

Comment: Using the term "constructor" to describe a literal is misleading, since there's no function call involved. As well, [parentheses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) can also be used to form an expression, e.g. `(x - 1) * x`, and tuples can be formed without parentheses, e.g. `t = 0, 1`.

Comment: Axblert, thanks, your answer was 100% correct, just making it more specific. wjandrea, thanks for clarifying. A literal still cause the Python engine to construct the object, no?

Comment: Its fine to get the details right, thanks for that ;) I hope my post does not reflect as much ambiguity now. As for the post from wjandrea : I am taking an Udacity course on data structures, they also happily refer to () and {} as constructors. It cannot be that poor then.

Comment: @Axblert yeah, then that Udacity course is simply wrong. But thanks for responding to feedback.

Comment: @Bennett Yeah, a literal still gets constructed into an object, but by the language itself, without calling a constructor. To clarify, a constructor is a *callable* that constructs an object -- in this case `tuple()` and `set()`. Anyway, mostly I wanted to clarify that the syntax for tuples vs parens is complicated in Python, and understanding constructors is a stepping stone to that.